# Should std::invoke work when the first input is an lvalue reference to a member function pointer?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, template-meta-programming

While trying to implement something similar to `std::invoke`, I noticed the following subtlety in the standard. I'm curious if anybody can give me a language lawyer explanation that helps decide whether libc++'s implementation is correct.

---

In N4868 (basically C++20), [[func.invoke]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/func.invoke) defines `std::invoke` this way:

> ```cpp
> template<class F, class... Args>
>   constexpr invoke_result_t<F, Args...> invoke(F&& f, Args&&... args)
>     noexcept(is_nothrow_invocable_v<F, Args...>);
> ```
>
> *Returns*: `INVOKE(std​::​forward<F>(f), std​::​forward<Args>(args)...)`.

In turn, [[func.require]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/function.objects#func.require-1) defines `INVOKE` as follows:

> Define `INVOKE(f, t_1, t_2, ..., t_N)` as follows:
>
> - [...] when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and [...]
> - [...] when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and [...]
> - [...] when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and [...]
> - [...] when `N == 1` and `f` is a pointer to a data member of a class `T` and [...]
> - [...] when `N == 1` and `f` is a pointer to a data member of a class `T` and [...]
> - `f(t_1, t_2, ..., t_N)` in all other cases.

My question is what should happen with the following snippet:

```cpp
struct Callable {
  int DoSomething() { return 17; }
};

int (Callable::*member_fn_ptr)() = &Callable::DoSomething;
assert(17 == std::invoke(member_fn_ptr, Callable{}));
```

This works under libc++, but in my implementation it causes a compilation error. That's because my implementation falls through to the "in all other cases" clause above, attempting to call the member function pointer as if it were a plain function pointer.

I thought this was a bug in my implementation until I read the standard a little more closely. The definition of `std::invoke` uses a forwarding reference for `f`, and clearly says it should be forwarded. In this case that means that it will be forwarded as an lvalue reference. Then in the cascade of logic in the definition of `INVOKE`, it seems like this *should* match the final case: `f` is not a pointer to a member function, but rather a reference to a pointer to a member function. And libc++'s implementation of `<type_traits>` agrees with me:

```cpp
static_assert(!std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(member_fn_ptr)&>)
```

In libc++ this works out only because the SFINAE for the first case of `INVOKE` [checks](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/6f27eb6ece324779d4d6a06b5685887afbc9465c/libcxx/include/__functional/invoke.h#L283) whether `std::decay_t<decltype(f)>` is a member function pointer, not `decltype(f)`.

**Is this a bug in libc++, a bug in the standard, or a bug in my understanding of the standard?**

Comment: My money is on sloppy wording, and an answer showing up with a LWG issue linked (potentially newly submitted).

Comment: Well, there's [**\[expr.type\]/1**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr#type-1) "If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`”, the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis." I find it inconceivable that the standard could have possibly intended for `std::invoke(member_fn_ptr, Callable{}));` to not work.

Comment: Yeah I agree it's likely intended that the snippet should work. But I don't think that wording explains it, because in the other parts of the definition of `INVOKE` they use `std::remove_reference_t` for the other parameters, so it's clear that they are assuming that the "referenceness" of the parameters carries through.

Comment: Since `f` is a `F&&`, of _course_ it's always a reference, and thus at a minimum you would need `remove_reference` to check its relevant type (i.e. `decltype(f)`, not just `F`). And since it's a forwarding reference, it's actually `remove_cvref` that's called for. I'm guessing libc++ uses `decay` as a lazy way to achieve pre-C++20 compat.

Comment: Yep, agreed. It seems the standard is inconsistent in this though: it is careful to use `remove_reference_t` etc. when discussing the other arguments, but not `f`.

Comment: It only uses those traits when discussing template specializations, and it spells them out so that you know _exactly_ which specializations are checked for; simple English like "is a" is not so formal, and it is again understood that since `f` is _always_ a reference type (and a forwarding reference at that), the only way it can ever "be a" pointer is if you necessarily `remove_cvref` on `decltype(f)` first to get at the relevant type.

Comment: I suspect that the language-lawyer wording you're looking for is in [\[func.require\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/function.objects#func.require-4), but I don't know how to spell that as a good answer. (Reposting comment as I linked to the wrong paragraph earlier, sorry for the spam.)